# How do I change Procedural Programming into OOP..? (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I am a beginner Java programmer and have toiled over this for quite some time. I need to convert the program below into OOP format and cannot get it to compile without error. I figured I would post the working non-formatted program rather than my failed and choppy attempts. If anyone could convert the below program into OOP, it would be very much appreciated. Please forgive any inefficiencies or sloppiness as I am new to this.

Thanks for helping :)

import java.util.Scanner;
public class EstimatePi
{

```
//Public static variables used because they are used throughout the different methods
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//2 * Math.random - 1 is used to guarentee that the max value is gonna be 1 and min is gonna be -1
public static double x = (2 * Math.random() - 1);
public static double y = (2 * Math.random() - 1);
public static double radius = 1.0;
public static double numOnBoard;
public static double totalPi;
public static int numThrows;
public static int trials;

public static int hits(double x, double y, int trials) {
    numOnBoard = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < trials; i++) {

        //Same Algorithm as above
        x = (2 * Math.random() - 1);
        y = (2 * Math.random() - 1);

        //If x2 + y2 <= r2 then its a hit on the board.
        if ((Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)) <= (Math.pow(radius, 2))) {
            numOnBoard++;
        }

    }

    //returns the num of hits on the board
    return (int)numOnBoard;
}

//Method to calculate pi, and store that data in an array
public static double[] piColumn( double numOnBoard, double numThrows)
{   double []piColumn = new double[trials];
    for(int i = 0; i < piColumn.length;i++)
    {
        //Formula to calculate the pi
        piColumn[i] = (4 * (numOnBoard) / numThrows);
    }
    return piColumn;
}

public static void main (String [ ] args)
{

    //The number of darts thrown per trial is asked
    System.out.println("How many times should the dart be thrown per trial?");
    numThrows = in.nextInt();     
    System.out.println();

    //The number of trials is asked
    System.out.println("How many trials do you want to simulate?");
    trials = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    //forloop to iterate the internal code while counter < trials
    for (int counter = 0; counter < trials; counter++) {

        //number of hits methods is declared as a integer
        int hits = hits(x,y,numThrows);

        //the calculation of pi is declared as a double
        double []estimatedPi = piColumn(hits,numThrows);

        //total = total + the estimatation of pi
        for(int i = 0; i < trials; i++){
            totalPi += estimatedPi[i];
        }

        //Formatting the output
        System.out.printf("%s %d %s %s", "Trial [",(counter + 1),"]", ": pi = ");
        System.out.printf("%1.5f\n",estimatedPi[counter]);
    }

    //The average pi is the total pi's divided by the number of trials the user enters
    double averagePi = (totalPi / trials / trials);

    System.out.printf("%s %1.5f\n", "Estimation of pi = ",averagePi);

}
```

}

Comment: JavaScript != Java, and jQuery is a JavaScript library, not Java.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - this question read a lot like a homework question and your claims that you've tried lots of things that didn't work seem a bit questionable as you don't provide any detail. Either way, this question is way too broad for this site, you need to ask specific questions. People aren't here to write code for you.

Comment: You've got things backwards: do post the attempts with a much more specific question. Otherwise the question reads more like an overly broad work order than a valid question.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  OOP is kind of a spectrum.  Some programs are more object oriented than others.  Yours is not very object oriented.  But there's no such thing as "converting a program into OOP".

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by the question and wrote a comic [project](https://github.com/GreenWizard2015/Extreme_OOP). I tried to make the code as more as possible object oriented, but stay in "domain" and do not use heavily design patterns,  frameworks, etc. Also, I tried to follow test-first ideology. You can view [commits history](https://github.com/GreenWizard2015/Extreme_OOP/commits/master) and see how the work went step by step.

Thank you, javacoder, for the experience and fun.